# Search API for Google Play Store

Tags: android, api, google-play

Is there a search API for the Google Play Store? I'm looking for anything like the  [Apple Search API](http://itunes.apple.com/search).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one, but it's an unofficial API:
http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Comment: Are there any current developments there??

Comment: the last changes were made in febuary 2012

Answer (score 1):

Calling the [WhereDat](http://wheredatapp.com/developers/) API is as simple as doing an HTTP Get, just replace "facebook" with your search parameter:

http://api.wheredatapp.com/search?q=facebook

And this is how a result will look like:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "category": "Social",
      "rating": 3.9948248863220215,
      "updated": 1435805622,
      "created": 1427510074,
      "icon_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ZZPdzvlpK9r_Df9C3M7j1rNRi7hhHRvPhlklJ3lfi5jk86Jd1s0Y5wcQ1QgbVaAP5Q=w300",
      "title": "Facebook",
      "download_url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana",
      "package": "com.facebook.katana",
      "ratings_count": 29588232,
      "short_description": "Keeping up with friends is faster than ever.• See what friends are up to• Share updates, photos and videos• Get notified when friends like and comment on your posts• P..."
    },
    {
      "category": "Business",
      "rating": 4.130451679229736,
      "updated": 1435644682,
      "created": 1427510616,
      "icon_url": "https://lh4.ggpht.com/vcyZimfIRlWrLarEpIj7MMSuqgwIkF4bx5nArKhFWsEqGclnPTAeLLK4cFiQ5QscRIEc=w300",
      "title": "Facebook Pages Manager",
      "download_url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.pages.app",
      "package": "com.facebook.pages.app",
      "ratings_count": 693199,
      "short_description": "Pages Manager helps admins connect with their audience and keep up with activity on multiple Pages, all in one place.• Post updates and photos and respond to comments ..."
    },
    {
      "category": "Social",
      "rating": 4.149935245513916,
      "updated": 1435881022,
      "created": 1427510065,
      "icon_url": "https://lh5.ggpht.com/sFV8zzvuM__JTl0QDhtp0sGMzBXKGrEQWLpdJr_DhNxHNIJ7rNbvEewTJdhULTjsgM0=w300",
      "title": "Facebook Groups",
      "download_url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.groups",
      "package": "com.facebook.groups",
      "ratings_count": 106446,
      "short_description": "This app gives you a dedicated space for you and your groups.See all of your Facebook Groups in one place. Discuss, plan and collaborate easily and without distraction..."
    },
    {
      "category": "Social",
      "rating": 4.336362838745117,
      "updated": 1435319250,
      "created": 1431991423,
      "icon_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Alon4Gigwl2DqrT36O6JMn-M40tinuxFHWROtv0TP8ozX8Sr5MiBM1CuHX-veqFhnKvQ=w300",
      "title": "Facebook Lite",
      "download_url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.lite",
      "package": "com.facebook.lite",
      "ratings_count": 95510,
      "short_description": "This version of Facebook is efficient with data and works in all network conditions.Facebook Lite:- Installs quickly — the app is less than 1 MB- Works on all Android ..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is one like mentioned above.
But is illegal to use it, We was consider to use it in our startup and we took a lawyer that check if we can use it.
After a small research (that based on the user agreement) he told us that it illegal to use this API.
Another reason to not use it is that you can't know when it will be stop working (if Google change something on their protocols the API will not work)